# Error(Data Corruption) occur while converting image into JSON and vice Versa

Tags: java, ios, json, parsing, client-server

While converting any image to data and followed by JSON it adds some special characters into the JSON string.

At iOS End (Server End)

> Image  -> NSData -> NSString  - > JSON String (This JSON string
>   contains some special characters)

On extracting at client end it corrupts the image data and that data is not properly decoded.

At Java End (Client End)

> Data -> Parse into JSON String -> Image data we get is Corrupted ->
>   Cannot able to form image

Code at iOS end  :

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(baseImgView.image);   
NSString *stringImage = [dataImage base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]; 
currentImage = stringImage;
```

Further created a dictonary called parameter and convert it into json using this :

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Please suggest me for the same to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to upload image to server ??

Comment: Yes I am uploading image using iOS server (created with help of GCDAsyncSocket library ) and extracting it on java end (client is made in java)

Comment: pls upload complete code

Comment: I have already update the iOS code  which I used to convert image to base 64 and then json string . This JSON string is passed to java server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS end

> Image -> NSData ->Base 64 String - > JSON String (This JSON string contains
>   some special characters)

Firstly it is converted into base 64 string using NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength(base 64 encoding) and then during conversion into json it uses NSUTF8StringEncoding (UTF8 encoding).

On java end we need to decode utf8 string encoding as well base encoding. 
import java.util.Base64;

One of stackoverflow link(donot remember exact link) gives an idea to that.Code goes like this :

**Here Image is encoded string .**

```
import java.util.Base64;

     try {
    // Encode using basic encoder
    String base64encodedString=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Image.getBytes("utf-8"));
    //   System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String (Basic) :" +base64encodedString);
    // Decode
        byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedString);    
        String replaceableImage =   new String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8");
        System.out.println("Original String:" + replaceableImage);
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
    }
```